# Is it okay to remove the inclusion of JQuery 3.3.1 in bootstrap if I'm already including a more up to date version?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I was having a really hard time getting bootstraps modals to work with JQuery ui's autocomplete. They weren't even used in the same place on the site but for some reason the modal stopped working when I included the cdns for JQuery and JQuery ui in my html, regardless of whether I included it before the bootstrap links or after.

Just to clarify, the end of my html body looked like this:

```html
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--JQuery and JQuery UI-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

What I ended up doing was removing the line

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and moving the jquery and jquery ui links above the bootstrap links:

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

All of a sudden, it's working. I am actually interested in why this wasn't working and then did (please feel free to shed some light on that), but I'm more concerned with whether or not what I did is safe/ok to do? I've been playing around with my code and it seems like it works fine, better safe than sorry though. Thanks!

Comment: This looks correct.
Because Bootstrap relys on jQuery and popper, you MUST include these first, because the scripts get executed in that order.
To the main question: a jQuery minor upgrade (3.x) seems generally okay, look out for major versions.
jQueryUI also relys on jQuery, so be sure to include jQuery first.
This also generally seems true for extensions like jquery-plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for more help we would need to see the error you were getting. Maybe there was something else wrong. I've tried to run your example with modals and both script placements work fine.

Anyway, it's correct to use a higher version of jQuery min instead of slim version. Min version has all the slim functionality.

Comment: I think the problem was actually arising from the fact that I didn't trigger the modal with `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#exampleModal"` (though I couldn't tell you why). It was just being triggered when a user tried to navigate away from the page they were on when they had already filled some values into the form. So I actually trigger the modal in jquery when a link in the navbar is clicked and the fields on the current form are filled to some extent.